# Performance issue with Snowflake views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two different instances of Snowflake. In first instance, I have a materialized view created, with brings data by joining fact table and 3-4 dimension tables.

```
Create View V1 as
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 
From Fact_t1 
inner join Dim1 
inner join Dim2 
inner join Dim3
```

On top of this, I have created a secure view. This secure view I share with second instance for reporting and BI purposes.

Now, when we are querying the secure view from second instance we are facing lot of performance issues with query running over 30 mins.

We are running this on Small or Medium based of requirement. We tried to change the size to XL, we gained some performance but it seems there is still a lag.

Following are the details of Snowflake DB:
Size: Small/Medium
Table Volume: 1.4 M (in Fact), 100K+ in Dimensions

Can you please suggest what else can be done? Is this happening because we are creating secure view over a view?

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake doesn't support multi-table join in materialized view. In first instance you are not creating a materialized view rather a view. Every-time a projection on view is done that data is retrieved from the underlying tables in remote storage unless the data is in cache and hasn't been changed in last 24 hours.

Since join of 100+ x 1.4M data is happening, which will bring millions of rows from remote storage. Join operation will take place on those million records thus the processing will take a considerable amount of time.

To improve performance, create a temp table instead and refer that in the secure view to get the best performance.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that.